# Having trouble with python 3 indexing

Tags: python-3.x

This is my first time posting so forgive me if it's a little off. I'm having a problem getting my code to index properly. I have to take a sentence and a letter from the user and then state how many times the letter was written in the sentence, while also accounting for upper and lowercase letters

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBuVC.png)

Comment: please add your code in your answer within a code block. To start a code block use 3  ` and to end it another three.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), 
and provide a [mre] _as [formatted text](/help/formatting), not a screenshot!_. [Why do we hate screenshots so much?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare `userInput[i]` with `userChar`, not `userInput`, because the string will always be the same whereas with `userInput[i]` it will give you the current letter.

tho doing:

```py
for letter in userString:
    if userChar == letter:
        ...
```

if better than

```py
for i in range(len(userString)):
    if userChar == userString[i]:
        ...
```